# Instructions for custom panels content types

Tags: 8, panels, chaos-tool-suite

I want to port a website from D7 to D8 that is based on panopoly and makes heavy use of custom ctools content type plugins as well as dynamic argument handling. I didn't find much useful information about doing the same thing in D8. What I found were very basic instructions about panelizing nodes and creating custom landing pages, the latter unfortunately without dynamic extraction of url arguments.

I would be happy to provide more information if necessary, but at the moment I'm primarily looking for documentation, code examples or similar that are developer oriented, and that provide more in-depth details about the APIs to be used and, if possible, a more general overview of how the pieces fit together.

Comment: I already found https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/drupal-8-now-object-oriented-plugins-drupal-7 which is probably a good starting point.

Comment: Actually I think this question is off-topic here, since you're asking to recommend off-site resources which is off-topic here.